# Fonts are displayed too large on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, mobile

All pages look exactly the same on mobile and desktop devices. Except one page on which the font is extremely large on mobile. I do not have an idea what the problem is. The first page is the index and is rendered correctly. The second causes the problem. The css is used in both.
This is how the index site looks like:
[image: index]
And this the problematic page:
[image: problematic page]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Polls overview - easypolls</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/polls/css/style.601432e006a7.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h2><a href="/">easypolls</a></h2>
    <hr />

    <form method="get" action="/search/">
        <input type="text" name="query">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <h3>Latest polls</h3>

    <ul>

        <li><a href="/2/">Is America great again?</a></li>

        <li><a href="/1/">Is this site great?</a></li>

    </ul>

    <p><a href="/create/">Create poll?</a></p>

</body>

</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Poll creation - easypolls</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/polls/css/style.601432e006a7.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h2><a href="/">easypolls</a></h2>
    <hr/>
    <h3>Poll creation</h3>
    <form method="post" action="/create/"> <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='ptZenNuGvnJtuBz1s0KFrGhdXvd4MRFQKopGgbCoFc3wVhe44szQKvAhw1y9nV9R' />
        <p> <label>Question:<input maxlength="200" name="question_text" type="text"/></label> </p>
        <p> <label>Publication date:<input name="pub_date" type="text"/><input name="initial-pub_date" type="hidden"/></label> <span class="helptext">Voting is going to be disabled until the publication date (Example: 2017-3-11 8:53). Leave empty for immediate publication.</span> </p>
        <p> <label>Allow multiple choices:<input name="allow_multiple_choices" type="checkbox"/></label> </p><input name="choice_set-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="6" /><input name="choice_set-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" /><input name="choice_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1" /><input name="choice_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="6" />
        <ul>
            <li> <label>Choice:<input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-0-choice_text" type="text"/></label> </li>
            <li> <label>Choice:<input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-1-choice_text" type="text"/></label> </li>
            <li> <label>Choice:<input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-2-choice_text" type="text"/></label> </li>
            <li> <label>Choice:<input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-3-choice_text" type="text"/></label> </li>
            <li> <label>Choice:<input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-4-choice_text" type="text"/></label> </li>
            <li> <label>Choice:<input maxlength="200" name="choice_set-5-choice_text" type="text"/></label> </li>
        </ul> <input type="submit" value="Create" /> </form>
</body>

</html>

*{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}
a{color:green}
a.navigation{margin:0px 5px}
a.share-link{margin-left:5px}
input[type=checkbox]{width:20px;height:20px;}
input[type=text]{margin:0px 5px;background:rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.25)}
```

Comment: Which tag displays it correctly, which doesn't, what's the relevant css for this problem? There's not enough context to answer this.

Comment: All text is displayed too large on multiple mobile devices. I will add the css but I do not set the font size.

Comment: Browsers have different default themes and font sizes (that may differ for each tag). You should set font sizes yourself to override the default themes. You can also use something like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to establish a default theme for all browsers.

Comment: As mentioned in the question all pages look exactly the same on mobile. Just this site has the too big font.

Comment: There's probably no way to help without seeing the real 2 sites and comparing the code used in each.